# Handling frequent updates in data layer, isn't immutabability a performance problem?

Tags: performance, architecture, android-jetpack-compose, immutability

Lets say I have a list of many items, displaying on the screen, e.g.

[list with three sliders, showing the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgRfn.png)

In my understanding, a typical architectural pattern with Jetpack Compose contains several layers

- UI Layer
- ...
- Data layer

The UI layer does not update itself, but triggers callbacks which in the end modify e.g. a list in the data layer (e.g. when dragging the slider). The UI layer observes the data layer and this is what actually updates the UI layer.

It seems quite common, that the data layer exposes its data in an immutable way to avoid threading issues. However, as far as I understand, dragging one slider will then require the data layer to create a copy of the whole list, as long as we want to stick to immutable data. Given that e.g. dragging a slider leads to very frequent data changes and that a list can contain a lot of values, this raises the question whether this is a good pattern in respect of UI performance. (I understand, that performance is often a matter of measuring, but for many problems, one does not have to measure since the answer is clear).

So I am wondering:

- Is the given pattern an obvious performance problem or not (I remember that for the classical "View"-System of Android it was strongly discouraged from allocating data in the onDraw-routine. Isn't the given case similar?)
- Did I understand the pattern incorrectly and this is not for frequent updates?

Research online does not give a lot of answers. E.g. room databases seem to emit lists, but I am not sure if it can deal with high-frequency updates.